# I'm getting the error DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message. in one of my commands it was completely fine yesterday, I didn't change anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

this code is for join-leave-logs in my servers, the code was completely fine yesterday and I didnt change a single thing in it and now im getting an error message whenever someone leaves or joins the server.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async(member) => { 
  const Channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('922828509515239426')
  const Channel_chillhub = member.guild.channels.cache.get('876212928041332776')
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('AQUA')
      .setAuthor('Member joined', member.displayAvatarURL())
      .setDescription(`**${member.displayName}** Joined ${member.guild.name}`)
      try{
        Channel_chillhub.send({ embeds: [embed] })
      } catch (e){
        Channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
      }
})
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async(member) => {
  const Channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('922828509515239426')
  const Channel_chillhub = member.guild.channels.cache.get('876212928041332776')
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTitle('Member left the server')
      .setDescription(`**${member.displayName}** has left ${member.guild.name}`)
      try{
        Channel_chillhub.send({ embeds: [embed] })
      } catch (e){
        Channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
      }
})
```

here's the error message when someone leaves a server: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

and here's the error message when someone joins it: TypeError: member.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Comment: What is the output if you put ```console.log(embed)``` before the try/catch block? Is it undefined?

Comment: @Borecjeborec1 yes it is

Comment: And if you remove all the ". attributes" (.setColor,etc...)? I mean, what's the output of ```console.log(new Discor.MessageEmbed())```. If it's not undefined try adding the embed before the .setColor, .setTitle, .setDescription.

Comment: wdym? everything including the .setAuthor?

Comment: Yes, because if the ```new Discord.MessageEmbed()``` works without it, the problem should be there.

Comment: just did it and it still crashes..

Comment: it says  this: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: But what does the ```console.log( new Discord.MessageEmbed())``` returns?

Comment: nothing, I dont think Im doing it correctly at this point

Comment: Ive just noticed that its  all the commands in my code, no matter what command I try to run it crashes

Answer (score 0):

For the error: `TypeError: member.displayAvatarURL is not a function`, try using `member.user.avatarURL()` instead of `member.displayAvatarURL()`.